How to capture screenshot of full screen using ElectronJS and NextJS (Nextron)
I'm trying to capture a screenshot of my entire screen using ElectronJS and NextJS (project was created using Nextron). I've been told to use the desktopCapturer API, but those tutorials want me to put the code in main.js. However, my Nextron project doesn't have a main.js file. Additionally, when I try to import desktopCapturer in a page like home.jsx, it says fs module is not found. I've done npm i fs, but it still doesn't work.
I have attached a screenshot of my file structure.


fs model available on server side may be you need to use api or somthing to run that code on server

@KamleshPaul how would we implement that in this file structure? because electronJS runs on the client side, what would we do?
